# ToProperty and BindTo - Get initial value without Subscribing

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, reactiveui

I'm using RXUI 6 with WPF in .NET 4.5.

I've been having trouble getting an initial value provided to my View when the ViewModel property it is bound to is backed by an `ObservableAsPropertyHelper`.

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/master/docs/migrating-from-rxui5.md#toproperty--oaph-changes):

> ToProperty / OAPH changes
>
> - ObservableAsPropertyHelper no longer is itself an IObservable, use    WhenAny to observe it.
> - ObservableAsPropertyHelper now lazily Subscribes to the source only when the Value is read for the first time. This significantly
>     improves performance and memory usage, but at the cost of some "Why
>     doesn't my test work??" confusion. If you find that your ToProperty
>     "isn't working", this may be why.

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22432822/observableaspropertyhelper-have-to-access-value-to-get-it-to-subscribe) which seems to address my same problem, but the answer provided works in testing and with a `ReactiveCommand`.  I cannot figure out the cleanest way to get this to work in my situation with any `IObservable<>` not necessarily a `ReactiveCommand` (oversimplified below).

Example ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<string> _message;

    public ViewModel()
    {
       var someObservable = Observable.Return("Hello");

        _message = someObservable
            .ToProperty(this, t => t.Message);
    }

    public string Message
    {
        get
        {
            return _message.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Example View Code-behind:

```
public partial class View : UserControl, IViewFor<ViewModel>
{
     public View()
     {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.WhenAnyValue(t => t.ViewModel.Message)
            .BindTo(this, t => t.MessageTextBlock.Text);
     }
     // ... IViewFor Stuff....
}
```

So right now, the Message TextBox will not contain the initial value.  However if in my ViewModel I was to add the line to the contructor:

```
this.WhenAnyValue(t => t.Message).Subscribe(s => {});
```

It will now fire off to the TextBlock because now there is a subscription.  So I'm guessing that the `.BindTo()` method never actually counts as a subscription?  Or it is laziness on top of laziness?  Does this empty subscription negate the performance benefits from it being lazy? Or should I not use `.BindTo()` and just use a `.Subscribe()` to assign the TextBlock?

**** EDIT ****
Ok, there might be something else going on in my code as I have not been able to reproduce this behavior consistently.  I will report back if I find the root cause.

*** EDIT 2 ***
I have confirmed that I had another issue that was causing the misfiring, not OAPH.  The .ToProperty and .BindTo seem to be working consistently as expected now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It will now fire off to the TextBlock because now there is a subscription. So I'm guessing that the .BindTo() method never actually counts as a subscription?

BindTo immediately Subscribes to the source and should kick off the OAPH. However, this Subscription won't actually *happen* until the View gets a ViewModel:

```
// Can't subscribe to (null).Message!
this.WhenAnyValue(t => t.ViewModel.Message)
```

Comment: Thank you Paul for the additional information and for a great framework.  I wish I could have figured out why my original issue was being fixed with that additional empty subscribe, but I ended up not having enough time to suss that out just for the sake of curiosity.  My root problem was in my IObservable and not OAPH.  Thanks again.